# Vim auto generating undesired JS comment blocks

Tags: javascript, vim

For .js files if I type

```
/**<Enter>
```

Vim creates

```
/**
 *
```

This is annoying, I don't want the asterisk on the second line added (it's also added to the start of any additional lines). It's probably being generated by one of the plugins I have installed (**this ended up being not the case, ignore what I have below this**) (I installed all with Pathogen), so I followed this process:

1. Uninstall a specific plugin (by moving its folder out of ~/vimfiles/bundle - let me know if this isn't the right way to uninstall Pathogen plugins)
2. Check in a .js file to see if the behavior was fixed (it never was)
3. Reinstall the specific plugin since apparently that wasn't the problem

I repeated that for all plugins (listed below) and couldn't make the behavior go away. Any ideas?

My plugins, they should all be fairly popular, uncontroversial choices:

- tlib_vim
- vim-addon-mw-utils
- vim-colors-solarized
- vim-easymotion
- vim-javascript
- vim-snipmate
- vim-snippets
- vim-handlebars
- NERDTree is installed, but not with pathogen so it wasn't easy to uninstall that and I didn't check it, but that seems an unlikely candidate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
:set formatoptions-=r
```

or add the following to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=r
```

formatoption 'r' automatically inserts the current comment leader after hitting `<enter>` in Insert mode.

See:

```
:h formatoptions
:h fo-table
```

Comment: For javascript files only: `autocmd FileType javascript setlocal formatoptions-=r` or add `setlocal formatoptions-=r` to `~/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is specified by the `'comments'` option.  See where it was set with

```
:verbose set comments?
```

Probably it is set in the default ftplugin for javascript.  Decide on a value you like, such as `:set comments=` or `:set comments=://`.  Then you can set this for future javascript files using an `:autocommand` as in @brettanomyces's answer or by using one of the methods described in `:help ftplugin-overrule`.  I recommend the third option described there.